# Fix Links / Move comments and highlights from one pdf to an identical pdf - Mac Preview

Tags: mac, pdf, preview

There's a professor where I study who tends to upload his lecture notes 3 pages at a time.

This means he started with 3 pages in the first class, and then after each class he adds 3 more pages to the last pdf file with the new material. Every time he uploaded 3 more pages, I've added them to my existing pdf with the older notes. Why not just download the new one, you ask?

Because I've been adding notes and highlights in preview (Macbook Air, High Sierra), and I don't want to lose them.

But now there's a new problem - the inner-document links are not working in my "aggregated" file, but they do work in my teacher's file.

So, I need one of two fixes:

1. Either fix the links in my "Aggregated" document, OR
2. Move all of my comments and highlights to the new pdf.

Comment: how did you agregate them? have you tried with pdfsam?

Comment: I've used preview itself - just appended the new pages to the document as they became available.

Comment: try usinbg PDFSam to merge, its quite good for things like this. its free

Comment: PDFSam is irrelevant here. Thank you anyhow:)